# Maximum product after K operations

Tags: arrays

Given an array A having 
N integers, you have to perform exactly 
K operations on it. In each operation you have to delete either the first or the last element of the array.We Define power of an array as the product of first and last element of the array. find out the maximum power he can achieve after performing exactly 
K operations.

Can someone give me an hint on how to approach this??

Comment: Have you worked on it? Do share your code. We can't do your homework/assignmens here

Answer (score 1):

This not the best solution, you can think for optimal solution, this is a hint.

```
public class Main {

static int maxPower(int array[], int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int k){
    if(leftIndex>array.length-1 || rightIndex < 0)
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    else if(k==0){
        return array[leftIndex]*array[rightIndex];
    }else{
        return Math.max(maxPower(array,leftIndex+1,rightIndex,k-1),maxPower(array,leftIndex,rightIndex-1,k-1));
    }
}

   public static void main(String[] args){
      int array[] = {1,4,5,7,2,4,9,4,6,2,7,0,5};
      System.out.print(maxPower(array,0,array.length-1,2));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Question requires a little observation

Lets us Consider an array of 7 elements

```
{1, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2}
```

Let k be 3 ?

if we observe there are few possibilities

1. Delete Index 6, 5, 4
2. Delete Index 0, 6, 5
3. Delete Index 0, 1, 6
4. Delete index 0, 1, 2

There can't be any other **possibility**

so we try to get the last and first element skipping the few starting index and few ending index

For

Case 1:
We skip none from starting and 6, 5, 4 from end, we will have the index 0, 3 as first and last element

Case 2:
We skip 0 index from starting and 6, 5 from end, we will have the index 1, 4 as first and last element

Case 3:
We Skip 0 , 1 index from starting and 6 from end, we will have the index 2, 5 as first and last life

Case 4: 
We Skip 0 , 1 , 2 index from starting and none from end, we will have the index 3, 6 as first and last life

Now consider every case and try to find out the maximum product

```
int findMaxPower(int arr[], int length, int k){
      int x = 0;
      int maximum = -1;
      for(int j=k;j>=0;j--){
          maximum = max(maximum, arr[x]*arr[length - j - 1]);
          x++;
      }
      return maximum;
}
```